# Eleven Labs Text to Speech Laravel Call

Tags: php, laravel, text-to-speech

I am using ElevenLabs Text to Speech API. This is my Laravel code:

```
$voiceId = "21m00Tcm4TlvDq8ikWAM";
$strippedScript = "To excel in programming, one must possess analytical thinking and attention to detail. Programmers debug and test their code rigorously, ensuring that it performs as intended. They establish clear rules and structures that guide the computer's behavior, just as scientists follow the scientific method to uncover the truth.";

// Text to speech from 11 labs
$apiURL = 'https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/'.$voiceId.'?optimize_streaming_latency=0&output_format=mp3_44100_128';

$apiKey = config('elevenlabs-client.api_token');

$response = Http::withHeaders([
    "xi-api-key" => $apiKey,
    "Content-Type" => "application/json",
    "accept" => "audio/mpeg",
])->post($apiURL, [
    "text" => $strippedScript,
    "model_id" => "eleven_monolingual_v1",
    "voice_settings" => [
        "stability" => 0,
        "similarity_boost" => 0,
        "style" => 0,
        "use_speaker_boost" => true
    ]
]);

//dd($response->getStatusCode());

$results = json_decode($response->getBody());

dd($results);
```

However I get an empty response (I should get the url to the text to speech file) and the HTTP response code is 200. Am I doing anything wrong? Anyone who has implemented this API in Laravel/PHP?